# getting error error calling tpl: error during tpl function execution for "environment.yaml" unclosed action while installing helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install helm chart, while installing it gets success with below file contents

```
Values.yaml 

errorAsync:
  enable: true

Environment.yaml

error-async:
  enable: {{.Values.errorAsync.enable}}
```

When I am trying to hardcode enable value in enviroment.yaml

```
Environment.yaml

error-async:
  enable: true
```

it gives : error calling tpl: error during tpl function execution for "environment.yaml: unclosed action

Comment: There seems to be no problem with this paragraph, can you provide more complete information？ (In addition, the format of the code in the question can also be adjusted, and the file name should not be placed in the code block)

Comment: You can also use the helm install --dry-run --debug or helm template --debug command to debug to get more detailed error information. (https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/debugging/)

Answer (score 1):

There was a space after value true, which was causing this issue

error-async:
enable: true <--- extra space